# Trigger a script when OOM Killer kills a process

Tags: shell-script, cron, monitoring, out-of-memory

I do a lot of work on in the cloud running statistical models that take up a lot of memory, usually with Ubuntu 18.04.  One big headache for me is when I set up a model to run for several hours or overnight, and I check on it later to find that the processes was killed.  After doing some research, it seems like this is due to something called the Out Of Memory (OOM) killer.

I would like to know when the OOM Killer kills one of my processes as soon as it happens, so I don't spend a whole night paying for a cloud VM that is not even running anything.

It looks like OOM events are logged in `/var/log/`, so I suppose I could write a cron job that periodically looks for new messages in `/var/log/`.  But this seems like a kludge.  Is there any way to set up the OOM killer so that after it kills a process, it then runs a shell script that I can configure to send me notifications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ask the kernel to panic on oom:

```
sysctl vm.panic_on_oom=1
```

or for future reboots

```
echo "vm.panic_on_oom=1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

You can adjust a process's likeliness to be killed, but presumably you have already removed most processes, so this may not be of use.
See `man 5 proc` for `/proc/[pid]/oom_score_adj`.

Of course, you can test the exit code of your program. If it is 137 it was killed by SIGKILL, which an oom would do.

If using `rsyslogd` you can match for the oom message (I don't know what shape that has) in the data stream and run a program:

```
:msg, contains, "oom killer..." ^/bin/myprogram
```